# unexpected query success

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM rps2_workflow
 WHERE     workflow_added > TO_DATE ('01.09.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
       AND workflow_finished < TO_DATE ('wtf', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
       AND workflow_status IN (7, 12, 17)
       AND workflow_worker = 159
```

I expect this query to fail, because of invalid date, but it returns 0

The plan for this query shows that on 8th step the invalid clause **is** processed:

```
8 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE RPS2.RPS2_WORKFLOW Object Instance: 1  Filter Predicates: ("WORKFLOW_STATUS"=7 OR "WORKFLOW_STATUS"=12 OR "WORKFLOW_STATUS"=17) AND SYS_EXTRACT_UTC("WORKFLOW_FINISHED")<SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TO_DATE('wtf','dd.mm.yyyy'))  Cost: 11  Bytes: 33  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 8 M  IO Cost: 10  Time: 1
```

If we comment out `AND workflow_status IN (7, 12, 17)` condition - then expectedly we get `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`

If we comment out `AND workflow_finished < TO_DATE ('wtf', 'dd.mm.yyyy')` then we get amount of records that fit that conditions (> 0)

How is this possible?

**UPD**:

The hint `/*+no_index(rps2_workflow) */` doesn't change anything (whereas in the plan we see that fullscan is performed)

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 254  Bytes: 31  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 34 M  IO Cost: 248  Time: 4       
2 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 31  Cardinality: 1     
    1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RPS2.RPS2_WORKFLOW Object Instance: 1  Filter Predicates: "WORKFLOW_WORKER"=159 AND ("WORKFLOW_STATUS"=7 OR "WORKFLOW_STATUS"=12 OR "WORKFLOW_STATUS"=17) AND SYS_EXTRACT_UTC("WORKFLOW_ADDED")>SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP' 2011-09-01 00:00:00') AND SYS_EXTRACT_UTC("WORKFLOW_FINISHED")<SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TO_DATE('wtf','dd.mm.yyyy'))  Cost: 254  Bytes: 31  Cardinality: 1  CPU Cost: 34 M  IO Cost: 248  Time: 4
```

Comment: @BoltClock: aw, cannot put sql in the end of the tags list :-S The issue is oracle-specific, not just a general sql question

Comment: I would guess the optimizer found no records (using indexes) for worker 159 with a status of 7, 12, or 17, so it didn't bother evaluating the rest of the query.   When you remove the status check, some records are found, so it needs to evaluate the TO_DATE function and causes the error.   Hard to say for sure what the query optimizer is doing though...

Comment: @Sparky: look at the last paragraph - if we remove "wrong" piece of query - it returns rows. I also thought so in a moment, but **there are** records with specified statuses

Comment: Interesting question. It's possible that in evaluating the other conditions, Oracle finds out there are no matching rowsand it doesn't ever get to that date conversion.

Comment: @NullUserException: indexes have been rebuilt with no changes, I wonder how else it can decide to skip that condition :-S

Comment: What comes back if you run   SELECT to_Date('WTF',dd.mm.yyyy') from DUAL?   I wonder if you are getting a NULL or something back that impacts the query?

Comment: @Sparky: `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`

Comment: So it throws exception as opposed to a NULL.   Sorry, I am out of guesses, but good luck finding an answer....

Comment: It probably found that every record satisfying all the other conditions have a NULL workflow_finished field. And anything compared to NULL is false so it doesn't need to evaluate the other operand.

Comment: @alexisdm: congrats! You got it ;-) Please put it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably found that every record satisfying all the other conditions have a `NULL` `workflow_finished` field.

And anything compared to `NULL` is unknown so it doesn't need to evaluate the other operand.

Comment: +1 Just a minor point: anything compared to NULL is unknown, not false, though it makes no difference here.

Answer (score 7):

If the optimizer decides that it doesn't need to evaluate a function, it won't, so the function will never throw exceptions:

```
select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 OR to_date('asdasdasd','asdasdasdas') > sysdate ;

         1
----------
         1
```

The function raises an exception only if it actually gets evaluated:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 AND to_date('asdasd','asdas') > sysdate ;
select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 AND to_date('asdasd','asdas') > sysdate
                                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

However, if the parser can decide *statically* that the query is invalid - because the function has the wrong type of arguments or the query has invalid types, then the parser will raise an exception before the optimizer gets a swing at it:

```
SQL> select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 or to_date('asdasdasd',0) > sysdate ;
select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 or to_date('asdasdasd',0) > sysdate
                                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER


SQL> select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 or to_date('asdasdasd','asdasdasdas') > 42 ;
select 1 from dual where 1 = 1 or to_date('asdasdasd','asdasdasdas') > 42
                                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

Comment: Even though you're absolutely correct - it is not an answer. Because the issue was a little deeper (not on predicate level, but on operand level). And alexisdm has guessed it correctly. +1 anyway

Comment: Ah, I didn't read through all the "read more" comments before answering :)

Comment: but anyway you did great work. This info definitely will be useful for any further reader. If alexisdm doesn't put his answer - I'll check yours (and will add the case caused that "strange" behaviour)