# Count(*) with order by not working on PostgreSQL which works on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Below is the Sql query which works on oracle but not working on PostgreSQL.

```
select count(*) from users where id>1 order by username;
```

I know that order by has no meaning in this query but still why it's working on oracle. Below is error on PostgreSQL

```
ERROR: column "users.username" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
Position: 48
```

**SQLState: 42803**

PostgreSQL version 9.6.3

Comment: Without `group by`, `count(*)` will return single record. what is the use of that `Order by`

Comment: That query is not valid ANSI SQL. However, the ORDER BY makes no sense since only one row is returned, so perhaps Oracle optimizes the ORDER BY away before raising an error.

Comment: Not every engine implements the syntax in exactly the same way. For example, in MySQL that same statement would not throw an error.

Comment: But order by is useless argument anyhow with count(*)

Comment: @Pரதீப் actually i'm migrating and app from oracle to postgres which uses Hibernate and there are some queries written like this so need to fix it without code changes, as same works on oracle, mysql.

Comment: `ORDER BY` should mention columns, which are i nthe select statement; Since you have only count(*) - this is not only meaningless, but also wrong, thus the error.

Comment: @VIPER yes agree order by is useless in above query but this works on oracle and mysql so need to fix which code changes.

Comment: @g00dy i agree with you but the only point is why it's working on oracle and mysql?

Comment: Why is it working on Oracle? Because a count of a set of rows does not depend upon the ordering of the rows. Well, I suppose it could if a DBMS had a bug in it. It seems pretty obvious to me that Oracle's implementation of the `SELECT` statement parser allows the syntax while PostgreSQL's implementation does not. Whether that was intentional on PostgreSQL's part is a question for that community. What might be interesting to you is that Oracle's CBO puts no SORT row source operation in the execution plan on 12.1. I'm often frustrated by their CBO but this time it did something good.

Comment: @gajendrakumar, probably Oracle and MySQL realize it's a one row result, and therefore removes the ORDER BY without analyzing it - so the error isn't found.

Comment: @jarlh agreed and PostgreSQL is handling the same problem with a different approach and tries to match your query to a standard way of using such queries and thus ask you to group by

Comment: @jarlh: for MySQL I would rather blame it to their sloppy implementation of `group by` which prefers returning random results rather then throwing and error.

Comment: @gajendrakumar: the real question is: why does Hibernate generate invalid SQL?

Comment: I was surprised to see that this query really doesn't result in an error in Oracle. It should, because it is invalid. I suppose jarlh is right supposing that Oracle doesn't detect the error, because its optimizer dismisses the `ORDER BY` clause immediately.

Answer (score 3):

As seen by [Oracle's execution plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cb88/1), there is no sorting after the rows are aggregated, which suggests that the SQL engine Oracle has implemented ignores that phrase.

Why doesn't it work in PostgreSQL -- because the people running Postgres know what they're doing ;)  Just kidding, but that question would be highly speculative for me, without seeing the Oracle vs MySQL source.  The bigger questions is if Oracle and MySQL allow for this by coincidence, or because Oracle owns both.

Final note:
If you're going to ask why similar software applications behave differently, I think it's also important to include what version you're referring to.  Even different versions of the same application may follow different instructions.

Comment: It reminded me my question from 2011 when I experienced an issue with oracle also running an incorrect query: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7327849/251311 In that case it also optimised out the incorrect predicate and simply evaluated query as if it was correct.

Comment: As to the "bigger question": We can be pretty sure that this is coincidence as the two products are very different from each other. The Oracle DBMS has a great optimizer that obviously immediately dismisses the `ORDER BY` clause, so the DBMS doesn't even bother to look at the clause more clausely and the error slips through undetected. MySQL on the other hand allows in a certain `SQL_MODE` unaggregated vales where we would suppose only aggregated ones possible. It kind of silently applies the aggregate function `ANY_VALUE` to such columns.

Comment: Yes and anyone reading this, this answer was supposed to be a comment that was too long and I was too impatient to finesse/edit it last night. The comments on the OP are correct. As to why this is still allowed, why Oracle permits it; (1) Im not sure the SQL standard describes how RDBMS should behave (2) there's always the possibility it could be for legacy reasons to not break old queries (entirely speculative) since it has relatively no impact

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the count of all records only, then there is no need of `order by` clause because it has no meaning even in oracle also. In such case remove `order by`.

```
select count(*) from users where id>1
```

If you are looking for username wise count, then there is a meaning of sorting on username and in such case you can use following query.

```
select count(*) from users where id>1 group by username order by username;
```

Hope your doubt will be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `with` statement for doing things like MySQL in PostgreSQL.

```
with cnt (cnt1) AS (  select count(*) as cnt1 from sample )
select *, c.cnt1 as len  from sample ,cnt as c;
```